# AS3 - Facebook.init returning both null for success and fail objects

Tags: actionscript-3, facebook-graph-api

I've done two tests

1. When I'm logged in, I get success as a valid object inside initHandler
2. When I'm not logged into the Facebook, I get success and fail both as null inside initHandler, so I've Facebook.login in my else case. which then prompts the user to login, but after filling in username and password, my loginHandler doesn't get called, how would my application know that he's logged in so I can go ahead and play the game, how it works out there? Please advise.

   ```
       private function connect(id:String):void { 
       Security.loadPolicyFile("https://fbcdn-profile-a.akamaihd.net/crossdomain.xml");
       Facebook.init(id, initHandler);
   }

   private function initHandler(success:Object, fail:Object):void { //success, fail are null
       if(success){

       } else {
           Facebook.login(loginHandler,{scope:"email, user_location"});
       }
   }

   private function loginHandler(success:Object, fail:Object):void {
       if(success) {

       } else {
           //permissions not given

       }
   }
   ```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Referring to point # 2 in my question, where my loginHandler wasn't called, I found another post that says to delay the login call, Here's the complete sequence of the code to run.

```
    public function authorize():void {
        var response:FacebookAuthResponse = Facebook.getAuthResponse();
        if(response && response.uid) {
            this.success(response);
        } else {
            this.init();
        }
    }

    protected function init():void { 
        Security.loadPolicyFile("https://fbcdn-profile-a.akamaihd.net/crossdomain.xml");
        Facebook.init(this.appID, this.initHandler);
    }

    protected function initHandler(response:FacebookAuthResponse, fail:Object):void {
        if(response && response.uid){ 
            this.success(response);
        } else { 
            setTimeout(this.login, 200);
        }
    }

    protected function login():void {
        Facebook.login(loginHandler, this.permissions);
    }

    protected function loginHandler(response:FacebookAuthResponse, fail:Object):void {
        if(response && response.uid) {
            this.success(response);
        } else {
            //not authorized
        }
    }

    protected function success(response:FacebookAuthResponse):void {
        //authorized
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure you get no response?

Maybe it's a matter of syntax - loginHandler( **result:** Object, fail:Object)...?

If you do get response, and the returned object is the issue, there is a way around it using Facebook.getAuthResponse()

```
protected function loginHandler(result:Object, fail:Object):void 
{
    if (result) {
        // --> LOGIN SUCCESS

        var resp:String = Facebook.getAuthResponse().toString();
        var fbid:String = resp.substr(1, resp.length-2).split(":")[1];

        if(id == "null"){

            //  un-authorized. probably you're in sandbox mode and the user is not a registered tester

        }else{

            //  continue using 'fbid' 

        }

    } else {
        // --> LOGIN FAILED
    } 
}
```

Comment: sorry that was a typo in my question, but not in the project, I fixed the code above in my question, but the login handler doesn't even get called in response to Facebook.login(loginHandler, {scoop"email, user_location"});

Comment: Okay, debugging.. try to render a login button upon init_fail instead of calling Facebook.login(), this way the login is triggered by user.

Comment: adding delay to login did the trick, I'm still not satisfied by the delay, it's a workaround but we shouldn't have delay, it should have worked without any delay, I don't know why, you can find my code below in in this question

Comment: This is actually an acceptable solution for me - thanks for the update!

Answer (score 0):

The init callback never fires for me.  It used to many months ago, but now returns null for both the success and fail objects.  You can test for a user ID with getAuthResponse as adifmac mentioned.  I do it this way:

```
// in the constructor or wherever, init Facebook without passing an onInitComplete callback
// then call function to check for session.

Facebook.init( APP_ID );
checkForActiveSession();

private function checkForActiveSession():void
{
    try
    {
        // looking for a user ID string from an active session
        var hasSession = Facebook.getAuthResponse().uid;

        if ( hasSession == null )
        {
            trace('null session, NOT logged in or has not given permissions');

            _userIsLoggedIn = false;
        }
        else
        {
            trace('active session, user logged in');

            _userIsLoggedIn = true;

            // now you can get user data
            getUserData();
        }
    }
    catch(e:Error)
    {
        trace('must be uploaded to server to test : ' + e.message);
    }
}
```

this method will not tell you specifically if they are not logged in, as this method shows a null session also if the user has not given the app permissions.  I find it works pretty well though despite that.  Note at this point that Facebook has been initialized and a call to Facebook.login should work.