# as3 facebook api: why does Facebook need js api

Tags: javascript, actionscript-3, flash, facebook-graph-api

I am using the as3 api's for facebook.

I have just switched from the FacebookDesktop class to the Facebook class and the first thing I see is that the Facebook class requires the javascript api ...

I do not want the extra layer.

so why is the JS api required for the Facebook class?

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that they're using their standard Javascript includes to get data back and forth to their servers. Their mobile apps are just wrappers around webviews that re-purpose all their on-line stuff, I'm assuming that they're doing something similar in AS3.

Comment: Dr. Dredel ... thanks. I understand that the js api is a wrapper ... maybe my question should have been, "why is the js wrapper needed?" especially considering that the FacebookDesktop class does **not** need it.

Answer (score 0):

Nothing is required in the html to use the Facebook AS3 API, unless you want specific functionality not provided by the AS3 API.

One example would be the setAutoGrow() method for resizing facebook tab applications, which is not provided in the AS3 API.  To use it you would also have to instantiate the JS API.

Comment: from my first tests, neither Facebook.init nor Facebook.login work without the js api ...

Comment: well, the init callback has been failing for some time.  and login won't work without init.  I have built apps strictly with the AS3 API and no JS API. See this post to get around the init issue:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10614734/as3-facebook-init-returning-both-null-for-success-and-fail-objects/10628363#10628363

Comment: seems like they are just hacking a solution ... I'm confused now ... are you saying that the as3 facebook api requies me to start hacking it to make it work? Because if that's the case I would just rather bypass the as3 api and learn the appropriate facebook-specified techniques directly. The only reason I would want to use the as3 for facebook api is because it should provide a robust and successful (and easy) interface to the facebook sphere. thanks.

Comment: "The init() , login() , and logout() methods of the Facebook class in the Adobe ActionScript 3 SDK for Facebook Platform call methods of the com.facebook.core.FacebookJSBridge.as class which in turn call methods of the Facebook JavaScript SDK." - http://www.adobe.com/devnet/facebook/articles/flex_fbgraph_pt3.html

Comment: also, Ribs, I believe that in the link that you provided, that the 'var hasSession = Facebook.getAuthResponse().uid;' **does** require the js api:

_Facebook.getAuthResponse()_ calls _js:FBAS.getAuthResponse()_ which calls _js-api:FB.getAuthResponse();_